# will mongodb replica set arbiter on a different continent slow down the cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 datacenters in the same region(dc1, dc2) and one datacenter in a different continent, 300-400 ms ping away from the first two - dc3. I've experimented with one member of the replica set in each datacenter, but the one far away (dc3) kept slowing things down (slow oplog, etc), so now i plan on keeping the arbiter overseas (dc3). This way, if one of the local datacenters (either dc1 or dc2) goes down, there will be enough members to vote.

But, having a bad experience with a replica set member overseas, i need to ask if somebody experimented with this kind of setup. Do arbiters in any way slow things down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Arbiters will affect the performance of aspects of the replica set. The arbiter will not be involved in read or write operations and won't have data replicated to it, naturally, but the arbiter is still involved in health checks and elections, and these will be affected by the ping times.